# obtaining unique number from a list of duplicate integers using java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I’m trying to obtain a only duplicated numbers list from a list of integers:

```
final Set<Integer> setOfNmums = new HashSet<>();
Arrays.asList(5,6,7,7,7,6,2,4,2,4).stream()
        .peek(integer -> System.out.println("XX -> " + integer))
        .filter(n -> !setOfNmums.add(n))
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```
The output is 2,4,6,7,7 
Expected : 2,4,6,7
```

I don’t understand how that’s happening.. is this running in parallel? how am I getting two '7'?

The hashset should return false if it exists and that used by the filter?

Yes I can use distinct, but I’m curious to know why would the filter fail.. is it being done in parallel?

Comment: That’s exactly what you requested. You are rejecting the first occurrence and accepting all subsequent occurrences. When an element occurs *n* times, you’ll add it *n-1* times. In case of `7`, n=3.

Comment: @Holger yes i got it... when the third 7 comes around the add returns false again, which causes the adding of it into the end list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your filter rejects the first occurrence of each element and accepts all subsequent occurrences. Therefore, when an element occurs *n* times, you’ll add it *n-1* times.

Since you want to accept all elements which occur more than once, but only accept them a single time, you could use `.filter(n -> !setOfNmums.add(n)) .distinct()` or you enhance the set to a map, to be able to accept an element only on its second occurrence.

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();
List<String> result = Stream.of(5,6,7,7,7,6,2,4,2,4)
    .filter(n -> occurrences.merge(n, 1, Integer::sum) == 2)
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But generally, using stateful filters with streams is discouraged.

A cleaner solution would be

```java
List<String> result = Stream.of(5,6,7,7,7,6,2,4,2,4)
   .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
      Collectors.toMap(String::valueOf, x -> true, (a,b) -> false, TreeMap::new),
      map -> { map.values().removeIf(b -> b); return new ArrayList<>(map.keySet()); }));
```

Note that this approach doesn’t count the occurrences but only remembers whether an element is unique or has seen at least a second time. This works by mapping each element to true with the second argument to the `toMap` collector, `x -> true`, and resolving multiple occurrences with a merge function of `(a,b) -> false`. The subsequent `map.values().removeIf(b -> b)` will remove all unique elements, i.e. those mapped to `true`.

Comment: I like the `x -> true, (a,b) -> false` part. Maybe you could add more details of how that line works, to future readers.

Comment: I agree with @MCEmperor `mergeFunction` in the second stream is very crafty

Answer (score 0):

You can use .distinct() function in your stream [check this out.](https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/java-stream-distinct-examples/)

Comment: @OxRyn yes i can use distinct, but i dont see why i would need that... since the filter should filter unless its doing it in parallel

Answer (score 0):

Since Holger already explained why your solution didn't work, I'll just provide an alternative.

Why not use `Collections.frequency(collection, element)` together with `distinct()`?

The solution would be quite simple(i apologize for the formatting, i just copied it from my ide and there doesn't seem to be an autoformat feature in SOF):

```java
        List<Integer> numbers = List.of(5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 2, 4, 2, 4);
        List<String> onlyDuplicates = numbers.stream()
                .filter(n -> Collections.frequency(numbers, n) > 1)
                .distinct()
                .sorted()
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .toList();
```

This simply keeps all elements that occur more than once and then filters out the duplicates before sorting, converting each element to a string and collecting to a list since that seems to be what you want.

if you need a mutable list you can use `collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new))` instead of `toList()`

Comment: `Collections.frequency` has to run over the entire collection to count the number of occurrences. The stream also runs over the collection’s elements and evaluates the filter for each element. So to process a list of 1,000 elements, this would perform 1,000,000 match operations, for a list of 10,000 elements, it would be 100,000,000 operations. And so on. This is also known as *quadratic time complexity*. So the reason not to use this approach is bad performance for larger lists.